# How to generate PDFs with outlines using the Springer LNCS templates?

Tags: pdftex, bookmarks, lncs

The PDF files generated by [Springer LNCS template](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) do not have PDF outlines. How to generate the outlines?

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact, that `Springer` may not allow `outlines` eventually, does `\usepackage{bookmark}` help?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No it doesn't help.

Comment: Well, please add a compilable document

Comment: @ChristianHupfer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `llncs` class explicitly sets the `tocdepth` counter to `0` (i.e.  `chapter` and `part` would be displayed in ToC and bookmarks), so there is no way to see `bookmark` entries for level below `chapter` with this counter value.

Increasing the `tocdepth` value to, say `2` or `3` will work and adding the `bookmark` package will provide the bookmarks down to `subsection` or `subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
\section{A}

\clearpage
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note: Depending on Springer's editing/publishing policies such settings might be rejected!

Comment: Thanks. This is purely for my archival version. Springer should never see this.